# How to modify an image (eg remove straight lines)

Tags: iphone, image, uiimage, ocr, tesseract

Good afternoon everybody. 
I want to process an image with tesseract. I managed to read a simple text. Now, I want to read the text that is put inside the cells of a table. I think that the best way to do it is to remove the straight lines of the table, but I've no idea to make it. Can you help me? 
Thank you in advance.